# How get array item correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have this request to database

```
@show = Question.where(:question_status => params[:id])
```

Then in @show variable I have this: `[#<Question id: 38, user_id: 1, question: "hi", question_status: 1, created_at: "2013-06-04 18:32:28", updated_at: "2013-06-04 18:32:28">, #<Question id: 40, user_id: 1, question: "urll", question_status: 1, created_at: "2013-06-04 18:34:57", updated_at: "2013-06-04 18:34:57">, #<Question id: 41, user_id: 1, question: "urll", question_status: 1, created_at: "2013-06-04 18:35:31", updated_at: "2013-06-04 18:35:31">]`

How get , for example, question field ?
I trying `@show.question` but have error `no defined method question`.

Comment: which database r u using?

Comment: if you asking for client...mysql

Comment: you want to take array of all question fields of Question table? See my answer.

Comment: Just try my solution, may it will help

Answer (score 1):

```
 @show = Question.find_by_question_status(params[:id]) 
and @show.question
```

If you us where statement then use:

```
@show.each do |show|
  show.question
end
```

Comment: check again by show = Question.find_by_question_status(params[:id]) and show.question

Answer (score 0):

@show is an ActiveRecord::Relation object(Array). It does not belong to Question class.

```
@show = Question.where(:question_status => params([:id]).first
```

if you are expecting only one result. Otherwise you have to iterate the array for each element

Comment: find method can search only by id or somthing else ?

Comment: sorry. thought he was searching for id when he passed id in params. see my edited answer

Comment: it give me only the last item in array which in question of this post

Answer (score 0):

Try this code at your rails console

```
@show = Question.where(:question_status => params[:id])
@show.each_with_index do |ques, index|
   p "#{index+1} :: #{ques.question}"
end
```

With the help of index, you will get the sequence number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You want to take an array of all question fields?

```
questions = Question.where(:question_status => params[:id]).map(&:question)
```

Then you can simply go like

```
questions.each{|question| puts question }
```

Comment: yes and other information. Can I use `map(&:question)` like this `map(&:question, &status)` ?

Comment: No you can't use like that. U want to take the status field also..?

Answer (score 0):

Use `@show.map(&:question)` . This will give you all the questions in array.

@show.question gives you error no defined method question because you are trying to operate question on array @show.

If you do `@show.first.question` it will give you question of first object.

And

If you do `@show.map(&:question)` it will give you array of question.

To get all the information.

```
@show.each do |show|
  puts show.question
  puts show.question_status
  puts show.user_id
end
```

You can optimize it as per you requirement.

Comment: I want get array information and then get from them all what i want, for example: question and status fields or only question field..

Comment: yes...it give me any field...but only for ONE item in array. When I searching by params[:id] - it is id of category and in array i get all information from this category. Your solution give me only ONE item.

Comment: i think i should use each in each